# How would you alphabetize an object in the simplest and easiest way possible (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Consider the following object as an example:

```
var object = {
  some_key: 'some value',
  some_other_key: 'some other value',
  AKey: 'notice that some will have underscores and some wont.'
  callBackl: 'http://google.ca'
}
```

Should become:

```
var object = {
  AKey: 'notice that some will have underscores and some wont.'
  callBackl: 'http://google.ca'
  some_key: 'some value',
  some_other_key: 'some other value',
}
```

I haven't found a lodash solution to this and a lot of solutions I do find on stack, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6566471/1270259), seem .... complicated. Maybe this isn't trivial?

**Ideas?**

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5467129/7947361

Comment: @OliviaRuth The issue with this solution is that its messy. Its not clean. Its gross.

Comment: It is what it is. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31102605/7947361 seems to be the most up to date. That old, and with that many votes, it seems as good as you are going to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: it appears as though I was incorrect when I first posted, newly defined Javascript specs state that (to my utter surprise) javascript objects do indeed have ordering ([Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key/31102605#31102605))! This being said, I still would not recommend attempting to order elements of an object itself, but rather to go with the key-sorting approach that I have described below. Object.keys(obj) as well as a few other edge cases appear to still have no guarantee of ordering and I would argue that that is good enough reason to stay away from depending on the order of the keys of your objects.

---

Original post below.

Unless I understand javascript incorrectly, the keys in a javascript object have no guaranteed ordering. This means that, in theory, I could create the object

```
{'a':'hi', 'c':'hey', 'b':'hello'}
```

And, on iterating through its keys I could get any possible ordering of 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

If you need to display your objects in any particular order, I would suggest accessing the keys of your object and sorting those and then accessing your object in the sorted order of your newly sorted keys. 
(Can be seen implemented here: [Is there a way to sort/order keys in JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658690/is-there-a-way-to-sort-order-keys-in-javascript-objects))

Comment: Not necessarily true. ES6 spec defines an order. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31102605/7947361

Comment: @OliviaRuth [Yes, but no](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/1048572)

Comment: Fair enough. I guess "try not to need to care" is probably still the best advice.