# How to maintain insertion order in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

Here is the format which my code is generating:

```
[
    {
        "certifications": [
            {
                "certificate": "NA",
                "completed_on": "2019-09-24T18:30:00.000Z",
                "tc_name": "TC-174195"
            }
        ],
        "firstname": "Dipak",
        "lastname": "Das",
        "email": "dasdipak99@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

And I wanted to design like below format:

```
[
  {
    firstname: "Dipak",
    lastname: "Das",
    email: "dasdipak99@gmail.com",
    certifications: [
      {
        certificate: "NA",
        completed_on: "2019-09-24T18:30:00.000Z",
        tc_name: "TC-174195"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Below is my code :

```
var user = [];
var certificate = {
  certifications: []
};

certificate["firstname"] = rows[0].firstname;
certificate["lastname"] = rows[0].lastname;
certificate["email"] = rows[0].email;

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
  certificate.certifications.push({
    certificate: rows[i].certification_names,
    completed_on: rows[i].completed_on,
    tc_name: rows[i].tc_name
  });
}
```

Any ideas how to maintain the insertion order? I am very new to javascript, apologies if i haven't explain well.

Comment: Based on your description, it looks like it _is_maintaining the insertion order. Your object first has `certifications`, then `firstname`, `lastname`, and `email`, and that's the format you're supposedly getting.

Comment: Hi @JLRishe - Could you please guide me to maintain `firstname `, `lastname `, `email ` and `certifications ` ?

Comment: Seems like you just need to do what you're already doing, but insert `certifications` at the end instead of at the beginning. I'm also a bit curious what you're really trying to achieve here. Trying to maintain object properties in a specific order is a bit futile, and I wouldn't recommend relying on that for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658690/is-there-a-way-to-sort-order-keys-in-javascript-objects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: agree with @JLRishe. Not sure why you would need to maintain the order of an object which is something you shouldn't rely on. It would be a different case if it was an array.

Comment: So is it fine to keep `certifications`, then `firstname`, `lastname`, and `email` in this order? @JLRishe @ibex

Comment: javascript objects does not guarantee the order of insertion https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/6904782.

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy JS does guarantee that for non-integer key names since 2015. Still not a good idea to rely on it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the empty certifications array after the firstname, lastname, and email:

```js
let rows=[{certification_name:"NA",completed_on:"2019-09-24T18:30:00.000Z",tc_name:"TC-174195"}]

let certificate = {}

certificate["firstname"] = "Dipak"
certificate["lastname"] = "Das"
certificate["email"] = "dasdipak99@gmail.com"
certificate["certifications"] = []
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
    certificate.certifications.push({
        "certificate": rows[i].certification_names,
        "completed_on": rows[i].completed_on,
        "tc_name": rows[i].tc_name
  })
}

console.log(certificate)
```

Comment: Insertion order is still not guaranteed because the standard does not mandate it. For the longest time Firefox refused to implement insertion order because not having insertion order was valid according to the spec but users managed to goad FF developers to do it. Note that any js engine may break this again in the future and the ES standards committee has refused to include it in the standard. **Do not** depend on object insertion order! Use other data structures if you want an ordered list

Comment: This misguided interpretation of "order" for an unordered data structure is so bad that the maintainers of the `go` programming language added a random number generator so that their map/hash data structure will always have random order - they consider the minor slowdown of the random number generator to be worth teaching naive programmers a valuable lesson and I agree

Comment: @slebetman I tested this on all the major browsers and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes but you still should not do it. It is not part of the javascript language - it is implementation detail. Never depend on implementation detail because it can change any time for any reason eg. if they change the structure of objects for speed optimizations. If that happens I know a lot of developers would consider the code that breaks as buggy instead of the browser

Answer (score 1):

Since ES6, there is a claim that the order would be

1. first numbers in increasing numbers
2. keys by insertion order

There is this [blog post](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#traversing-the-own-keys-of-an-object) and this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202095/325418).

But your lines of

```
var certificate = {
  certifications: []
};
```

made `certifications` the first property. So you would need:

```js
var certificate = {};

certificate["firstname"] = "Albert";
certificate["lastname"] = "Lee";
certificate["email"] = "a@b.com";
certificate["certifications"] = [];

certificate.certifications.push({
  certificate: "Java",
  completed_on: "2020/01/02",
  tc_name: "java2020"
});

console.log(certificate);
```

To better guarantee an order, use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), to keep the original insertion order of the keys. Usually you may not need it, but only for some reason if you want the order, and can have such order in a for-of loop:

```js
var certificate = new Map();

certificate.set('firstname', "Albert");
certificate.set('lastname', "Lee");
certificate.set('email', "a@b.com");
certificate.set("certifications", []);
certificate.get("certifications").push({
  "certificate": "Java",
  "completed_on": "2020/01/02",
  "tc_name": "java2020"
})

console.log(certificate);

for (e of certificate) console.log(e)
```

StackOverflow won't print anything for:

```
console.log(certificate);
```

using Node or Chrome, it is:

```
Map {
  'firstname' => 'Albert',
  'lastname' => 'Lee',
  'email' => 'a@b.com',
  'certifications' => [
    {
      certificate: 'Java',
      completed_on: '2020/01/02',
      tc_name: 'java2010'
    }
  ]
}
```