# Why Google App Script Keep on randomly sorting my Object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an application running under Appscript

**app.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
        
}

function getInputNames(form){
   var key = Object.keys(form);
   return key;
}
```

**form.html**

```
<form id="myForm">
<input name="Name" id="myName" type="text"><br>
<input name="Data" id="mydata" type="text"><br>
<input name="Fata" id="myFata" type="text">
<input type='submit' value='Upload' onclick="this.value='Grabbing Names..';google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).getInputNames(this.parentNode);return false;">
</form>
```

**Expected Output**

```
Name,Data,Fata
```

**What Result I Get Always Random**

```
Data,Fata,Name or Fata,Fata,Name
```

the problem is that the object is always randomly sorting which is a big problem for me
is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: You won’t get `Fata,Fata,Name`. Anyway, object keys are not meant to be ordered. If order is important, use an array with a specified order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to sort/order keys in JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658690/is-there-a-way-to-sort-order-keys-in-javascript-objects)

Comment: @user4642212 sir on the other hand is there a way where I can get the name of the input fields from my from that follows their orders?

Comment: can you share the full script and the html? Avoid providing personal information.

Comment: @Kessy that's all

Comment: @SnowAngel I do apologize but, how do you get the values? How do run it?