# how to sort and get last value and index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i create a let in JavaScript below format

```
  let  map={'431':232,'432':123,'433':120}
```

i want to order the map into following format. order by value.

```
map={'433':120,'432':123,'431':232}
```

at  last i need to store index and value as numbers.

```
int1=431 // index as number

int2=232 // values as number
```

Comment: please look into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658690/is-there-a-way-to-sort-order-keys-in-javascript-objects

Comment: Your question lacks focus on the part you have a problem with? Setting up the let? Doing the sorting? Determining the indexes? Storing them in variables (or better in an array)? You could fix that by providing a [mre] of what you already have and remove those things from the question you already have achieved. If the problem is with the frist part please remove the all other parts and only as about the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it creates your goal object and what you want you can find.

```js
let  map={'431':232,'432':123,'433':120}
var keys = [];
var values = [];
for(var k in map) keys.push(parseInt(k));

for(var v in map) values.push(map[v]);
values = values.sort().reverse();
let finalObj=[];
for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
  let obj = {};
  obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
  finalObj.push(obj)
}

console.log(finalObj[finalObj.length-1])
```

Comment: how i can get the last key and value as number..?

Comment: I edit my answer to get last key and value. I hope it helps you. if you get help vote my answer.

Comment: did you test it ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Convert the object to an *entries* array
2. Sort it by key (`entry[0]`)
3. Grab the last entry by index or via `Array.prototype.pop()`

```js
let map = {'431':232,'432':123,'433':120}

const sorted = Object.entries(map).sort(([ key1 ], [ key2 ]) =>
  key2 - key1)
  
const [ int1, int2 ] = sorted[sorted.length - 1]

console.info(int1, int2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.entries`, sort them and take the first element (using destructure)

```js
let map = { '431': 232, '432': 123, '433': 120 };

const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(map).sort(([a], [b]) => +a - +b);

console.log(key, value);
```