# Typescript Object sort by Key

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was working with typescript with the code below, but it didn't sort it up like the result I tried in JavaScript.

```
const param = {
            "b1": "val1",
            "z1": "val2",
            "k1": "val3",
            "a1": "val4",
            "c1": "val5",
            "s1": "val6",
            "u1": "val7",
        };

const sortable = Object.entries((param))
            .sort(([,a]:any, [,b]:any) => a - b)
            .reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({ ...r, [k]: v }), {});
console.log(sortable);
```

In JSFiddle, the expected result returns successfully (omitting any declaration type)

```
{
  a1: "val4",
  b1: "val1",
  c1: "val5",
  k1: "val3",
  s1: "val6",
  u1: "val7",
  z1: "val2"
}
```

Is there a typescript-specific function I need to `add/remove`?

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQNUgADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRogLFFTBPB3AExcwABT0xnM9zsyhc9wASmCKhwDQ8ZC8iElzhB7Bo3zcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiS58D0Ii8AoZTJZggFSRxAvADlQAHJhAA5SASAVBFQAeW+ZF2gldWkgx1QjgUrmkeFATgtOlGWH0KAQiBhwiudokkuiIgMHBx3RYbC43CCsvg1JoBEcTL5oAA3ooAJBzgXSACMAvygp0DGgy94s-nAC9l6uBevoAAmAXbuczgXxA9rjcAZnPO6vDFvR43ABYn5eBbA38eAFZv3nQR-w3AA2YCr3YMDoAAdmAgBfABuSkhxpa5JQLbkUH5VNpAAK0gWBUACVFUEofQVRVUcyCZPUDUvAJ5TIVBqIAbV4BgAF18jMPB+E46ReP4vU+QAPmMcppEYucAicbh2AsaiyEE+J+B0bixN5SSVUnUAAkM1TQHY+JeNAHRQEQvV+EnazULlBVICVeBVRY7D9WQoA)

Comment: You have two question? first is sort? what about `add/remove`?
be clear about `Is there a typescript-specific function I need to add/remove`.

Comment: You can never guarantee order of keys in a javascript object

Comment: You're comparing the "1"s in your keys, so the result looks expected.

Comment: This is code smell. While brk's assertion is [not necessarily still true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/114900) it's really not idiomatic JavaScript. I also cannot conceive of a good reason to use object property ordering to guarantee ordering, rather than another data structure like an array. Furthermore, in my browser, if I `console.dir(param)`, with your original ordering, the browser prints an object _with lexically-sorted properties_ ignoring the underlying representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort an abject by key you can use `Object.keys` and then use sort function like this:

```
const sortable = (Object.keys(param) as Array<keyof typeof param>)
                .sort().reduce((r:any, k:string) => (r[k] = param[k], r), {});
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=72&pln=11&pc=3#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQwE4ILYwLwwN4CgCQhARAEYCMRAXDEQG4IA2FANAcQF4XV2MBMRrQviIBrLjXoMAzALbCE4ngwAssoUWCLJAVjXEIWxgDY9wgK6GGAdj0BfANy5cMGKEiwIIJFAQkGAU0wYAAoAeRIAK39gKAA6EX8ATwhgxBRUAEoYBAgYAEEkFESAHgTEkAAzGChEuH9K%20GQ0AD4M5xcOzq6YWM9vYIzYpH8AEzNgf2DgpEoEMETmGBEsjGaQpABtEQBdILS0Le3FpAzF7FsMxyc3TwDYhhAAc2C%20nz9-S6A)

Comment: plus one, why did you omit the type for `k` in the reduce params? I would expect `k:string`

Comment: @Timo you are right `k` is string. I will update the answer. Thank you

Comment: If you run your changed code in playground, you get a `ts7053` warning, maybe because tsc cannot guarantee/know that all keys are strings and thinks of numbers instead because indexes by design are numbers and not strings. No idea how to fix it, the code runs nevertheless

Comment: [I added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73919387/1705829) a slight different solution to yours with `ES6` and `spread op`.

Comment: @Timo nice approach