# Sort JavaScript object by key like this {"ADF_1":"","ADF_2":"","ADF_3":"","ADF_4":""}

Tags: javascript

```
const data = {"ADF_3":"","ADF_2":"","ADF_1":"","ADF_7":"","ADF_17":"","ADF_6":"","ADF_18":"","ADF_5":"","ADF_15":"","ADF_4":"","ADF_16":"","ADF_9":"","ADF_19":"","ADF_8":"","ADF_20":"","ADF_10":"","ADF_13":"","ADF_14":"","ADF_11":"","ADF_12":""};

{"ADF_1":"","ADF_2":"","ADF_3":"","ADF_4":"","ADF_5":"","ADF_6":"","ADF_7":"","ADF_8":"","ADF_9":"","ADF_10":"","ADF_11":"","ADF12":"","ADF_13":"","ADF_14":"","ADF_15":"","ADF_16":"","ADF_17":"","ADF_18":"","ADF_19":"","ADF_20":""};
```

Comment: care to explain or give more details about your question and format that into code while at it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658690/is-there-a-way-to-sort-order-keys-in-javascript-objects <- here is a case like yours

Comment: Please follow the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658690/is-there-a-way-to-sort-order-keys-in-javascript-objects

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {"ADF_3":"","ADF_2":"","ADF_1":"","ADF_7":"","ADF_17":"","ADF_6":"","ADF_18":"","ADF_5":"","ADF_15":"","ADF_4":"","ADF_16":"","ADF_9":"","ADF_19":"","ADF_8":"","ADF_20":"","ADF_10":"","ADF_13":"","ADF_14":"","ADF_11":"","ADF_12":""};

console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).sort(([a],[b])=>
  a.localeCompare(b,undefined,{numeric: true}))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {"ADF_3":"","ADF_2":"","ADF_1":"","ADF_7":"","ADF_17":"","ADF_6":"","ADF_18":"","ADF_5":"","ADF_15":"","ADF_4":"","ADF_16":"","ADF_9":"","ADF_19":"","ADF_8":"","ADF_20":"","ADF_10":"","ADF_13":"","ADF_14":"","ADF_11":"","ADF_12":""};

const sortedData = {};
Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.replace("ADF_", "")) - parseInt(b.replace("ADF_", "")))
                 .forEach(key => sortedData[key] = data[key]);

console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: Worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/38218582#38218582